# QFontInfo not returning correct font family

Tags: macos, qt, fonts

I am trying to use a Braille-only font that Apple made available on Snow Leopard, called `Apple Braille` to simulate a braille display.

I'm trying to use Qt 4.7.3 for the job, but so far I've had no luck trying to get it to load the font. Check my code bellow:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QFontDatabase>
#include <QFontInfo>
#include <QStringList>

Q_DECL_EXPORT int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QScopedPointer<QCoreApplication> app(new QCoreApplication(argc, argv));

    int id = QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont(
        "/System/Library/Fonts/Apple Braille Outline 8 Dot.ttf");

    qDebug() << "Registered font Family is"
             << QFontDatabase::applicationFontFamilies(id).join(",");

    QFont desired_font("Apple Braille");

    qDebug() << "Got" << QFontInfo(desired_font).family();

    return app->exec();
}
```

What I get on my console is:

> Registered font Family is "Apple Braille"
>
> Got "Helvetica"

Somehow it is loading the correct font, but not using it. I've checked the font file with `Font Book.app` and it is a valid True Type font. Qt is not returning an error, so what can I do to get it to load and use the font?

Comment: This works for me on OS 10.8.1 with Qt 4.8.2 — `Got "Apple Braille"`.